# Force reload CSS file on ipad home screen app

Tags: css, html, ipad, caching, homescreen

I have an HTML/JS/CSS app that's been added to the home screen on an iPad.  This is **not** a cached HTML app - it doesn't have cache.manifest and is supposed to pull data from the server.

For some crazy reasons, it's cached the CSS file and refuses to get the new version from the server.  Mobile safari does show the latest version correctly.  I deleted the home screen icon, killed the app in the recent list, cleared safari cache, cookies and website data, killed safari in the recent apps and and re-added the home screen icon again after ensuring that I am seeing the latest data on safari.  When I run it, it's still using the old cached version of the CSS.

It's worth noting that it took about 20 restarts for it to see the updated images and javascript files, but it's still not seeing the new css.

Any pointers are more than welcome.

P.S. I managed to solve this on my own ipad by connecting it to the computer, going into the dev console and refreshing from there, however I can't force the client to do the same (least because the client doesn't have a mac) - I need a way to force it to refresh the files from ipad alone, without involving any other hardware.

Answer (score 3):

I have run into this a few times.

The simplest solution is to add a version number after your css link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?ver=1" type="text/css" />
```

Just change the version number when making edits - that should force the device to reload the CSS.

Comment: This works indeed. But I cannot impossibly change all my files and referring js function to this only because this stupid iOS bug. Is there any other way? Jesus, this makes me suffer.

Comment: This is an old answer- it might not still be accurate

Answer (score 3):

If you are using php, you can add the file modification timestamp to the css link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?ver=<?= filemtime('style.css') ?>" type="text/css" />
```

This would force it to reload the file each time you change it.

See a more complete explanation here: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php#81194

And here: 
https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/05/04/force-css-changes-to-go-live-immediately/